# Regex to parse Cisco log messages

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex that will parse the following Cisco log messages correctly:

```
<191>45902: DC-SWITCH2: Aug 30 18:15:16.478: %SFF8472-3-THRESHOLD_VIOLATION: Te0/2: Rx power high warning; Operating value:  -0.8 dBm, Threshold value:  -1.0 dBm.
```

Desired output:

```
Te0/2: Rx power high warning; Operating value:  -0.8 dBm, Threshold value:  -1.0 dBm.
```

And:

```
<191>45902: DC-SWITCH2: Aug 31 19:17:30.147:  sensor num : 10 sensor_value :33, high :110 low:85
```

Desired output:

```
sensor num : 10 sensor_value :33, high :110 low:85
```

I have developed the following regex for the first case, but I cannot fathom how to make the mnemonic `%STRING` section optional:

```
>\d+:\s.+?:\s.+?(?=:\s):\s%.+?(?=:\s):?\s(.+)
```

It returns the desired result for the first example, but for the second I get:

```
10 sensor_value :33, high :110 low:85
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to make the part that checks for the `%STRING` non-capturing.
Something like this:

```
>\d+:\s.+?:\s.+?(?=:\s):\s(?:%.+?:)?\s(.+)
```

See https://regex101.com/r/F30ALK/1

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that exact thing and it didn't work - thanks!

Comment: Non-capturing, and non-required, actually - ?: at the start, and ? at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something generic like

```
\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}.*? (\b[A-Za-z].*)
```

where the required output will be in the Group 1.

Example shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/Yzqg6v/1)